# Using schedule_attributes with ice_cube to populate a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, ice-cube

I'm using Schedule Attributes with Ice Cube to schedule some events with a form, I need to populate the form in editing as in [this example](https://github.com/avit/schedule_attributes#schedule_attributes-1):

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
[...]
  <%= f.fields_for :schedule_attributes do |schedule| %>
    Start Date <%= schedule.datetime_select :start_date %><br>
  <% end %>
[...]
<% end %>
```

Can someone show me how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: I'm attempting to do the same thing. I was considering creating a table-less model and creating a bunch of properties such as repeat_type :Week, :Day, :Month, :Year etc and using that to build a form with...

Comment: Hey! Did you happen to solve this issue?

Comment: @dgilperez no, not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should give https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select a shot?